Error Encountered During Hybrid Search in Milvus
I am trying to perform a hybrid search using Milvus with the provided code:
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_milvus.retrievers import MilvusCollectionHybridSearchRetriever
from langchain_milvus.utils.sparse import BM25SparseEmbedding
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings
import torch
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from database_operation import initialise_milvus, data_ingest_milvus_db, data_load_from_milvus
import time
from groq import Groq
import os, logging
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
from pymilvus import (
Collection,
CollectionSchema,
DataType,
FieldSchema,
WeightedRanker,
connections,
)

CONNECTION_URI = "http://localhost:19530"
#export OPENAI_API_KEY=<your_api_key>

folder_path = "/home/rndadmin/dev/test/"

def preprocess_document(docs):
table_fragments = {}
data_string = ''

for doc in docs:
    if doc.page_content:
        # Extract and process HTML table fragments
        if doc.metadata.get("text_as_html", ''):
            table_data = doc.metadata.get("text_as_html", '')
            # Parse the HTML
            soup = BeautifulSoup(table_data, 'html.parser')
            
            # Remove style attributes
            for tag in soup.find_all(style=True):
                del tag['style']
            # Remove extra white spaces
            for tag in soup.find_all(["th", "td"]):
                if tag.string:
                    tag.string = tag.string.strip()
            
            # Get table ID or another unique identifier
            table_id = soup.find('table')['id'] if soup.find('table') else 'unknown'
            cleaned_table = str(soup.table)
            
            if table_id not in table_fragments:
                table_fragments[table_id] = []
            table_fragments[table_id].append(cleaned_table)
            
        data_string += doc.page_content + "\n\n"

# Combine table fragments
combined_tables = []
for table_id, fragments in table_fragments.items():
    combined_table = ''.join(fragments)
    combined_tables.append(combined_table)

# Create final document with combined tables
final_doc = docs[0]
final_doc.page_content = data_string + "\n\n".join(combined_tables)
source = docs[0].metadata.get("source", '')

if source:
    file_path = Path(source)
    file_name = file_path.name  # storing only filename
    final_doc.metadata = {"source": file_name} if file_name else {"source": source}
else:
    final_doc.metadata = {"source": source}

final_doc = [final_doc]
print(final_doc)
return final_doc

My retriever is created sucesfully but when I am doing any query to the retriever , I am getting below error :
\*\*RPC error: \[hybrid_search\], \<MilvusException: (code=65535, message=fail to search on QueryNode 3: worker(3) query failed: Assert "static_cast(field_meta.get_data_type()) == static_cast(info.type())" at /go/src/github.com/milvus-io/milvus/internal/core/src/query/Plan.cpp:48  
=\> vector type must be the same, field sparse_vector - type VECTOR_SPARSE_FLOAT, search info type VECTOR_FLOAT)\>, \<Time:{'RPC start': '2024-08-14 04:47:17.316357', 'RPC error': '2024-08-14 04:47:18.708334'}\>

MilvusException: vector type must be the same, field sparse_vector - 
type VECTOR_SPARSE_FLOAT, search info type VECTOR_FLOAT

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this issue?

I could not find your search or query in provided code.
